# get data from GUI every 10s java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to get data from GUIinput when click on button , I write this code it get data butthen go into infinite loop

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println(name.getText());

    }
```

Comment: You have to put your infinite loop on a separate thread - and you should make it a demon so your application may still terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get data from GUIinput when click on button

You are using `Thread.sleep(...)` on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which will prevent the GUI from responding to events until the loop is finished.

Don't use Thread.sleep(...) on the EDT!!!

There are two common solutions:

1. Use a Swing Timer to schedule an event every 10 seconds.
2. Use a separate Thread. Then in this thread you can use Thread.sleep() because it won't affect the EDT. Typically you would use a `SwingWorker` and "publish" a result every 10 seconds.

So take a look at the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You will find topics on:

1. `How to Use Swing Timers`
2. `Concurrency in Swing` - which will explain about the EDT and SwingWorker.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get it, question name says you want your data every 10s and then you say that you get into infinite loop ( ??? )

remove `while(true)`  to escape infinite loop

Comment: I need loop because I must keep reading and update data every 10 second
if I remove while it display data just once

Comment: but isn't then an infinite loop exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: I have GUI with two text field and button
Ineed Keep reading it every 10s and print data

Comment: and what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I wrote the code upper 
 I run app and click button , it run and print but after programm not responding for any command or click and I can't stop GUI or programm

Comment: because you're in an infinite loop. please read more about this topic https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm